# Ending timer in Python's Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, datetime, timer, tkinter

I have a problem, namely I get an error when I want to close a window with a timer, and I don't know what to do:

```
class App():
def __init__(self):
    self.root = Tk()
self.root.geometry("100x50+50+50")
    self.done_time=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=a) 
    self.label = Label(text="")
    self.label.pack()
    self.update_clock()
    self.root.mainloop()

def update_clock(self):
    elapsed = self.done_time - datetime.datetime.now()
    h,m,s,fs = elapsed.seconds/3600,elapsed.seconds/60,elapsed.seconds%60,(elapsed.microseconds%60)
    #fractional_seconds = math.floor(elapsed.microseconds/1000000.0*100)
    self.label.configure(text="%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d"%(h,m,s,fs))
    self.root.after(100, self.update_clock)
while s == 0:
    self.root.destroy() #====> here is the problem
```

Comment: You want an infinite loop where you destroy the root window over and over and over again?

Answer (score 1):

To cancel a pending update, you need to save a reference to the job id. Then you can call `after_cancel`, giving if the job id.

```
self.job_id = self.root.after(...)
...
self.root.after_cancel(self.job_id)
```

Comment: so i can do something like that?

self.job_id = self.root.after(100, self.update_clock)
while s==0:
self.root.after_cancel(self.job_id)

Comment: @Jorgusss: You wouldn't do it in a loop. There's only one job to cancel.

Comment: but i don' t exactly know how to use that in that function, becase if i use it without loop it stops in less than a second